# How to make row scroll (overflow) on x axis when reach max width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want if more than max width it should be able to scroll. I tried setting the width to 100% and overflow-x:auto and white-space: nowrap as described in other stackoverflow posts but it doesnt work for bootstrap col. i also tried using flex and flex overflow and also tried by adding container-fluid but it still have same outcome although the scroll bar is showing but cannot scroll

For my current output, if col is more than 18 it will break and go to new line which is not what i want, i want it to be able to scroll instead break line into new row

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
   <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div  style="width:100%; overflow-x:auto; white-space: nowrap;">
         <form id="TICKETSALE_ORDERTICKETSELECTSEATFORM" action="TICKETSALE_ORDERTICKETSELECTSEATFORM.php" method="POST">
            <div class="row row-eq-height mb-4 px-2 py-2" style="background-color:purple; height:40px;">
               <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12" >
                        <label class="text-center " style="color:white; font-weight:900;">SCREEN</label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                for($a=1; $a<=$row_Q1[0]['ROW']; $a++){
                    //row
            ?>
               <div class="row row-eq-height ">
            <?php
               for($b=1; $b<=$row_Q1[0]["COL"]; $b++){
                  //col
            ?>
               <div class="col">
            <?php
               $RowKeyExist = checkIfKeyExist($row_Q2, $a, $b);
                  if($RowKeyExist!== false){
            ?>
                     <div id=<?=$a.",".$b?>>
                        <div class="form-check pl-0">
                           <label class="fas fa-chair SEATIMAGE">
                           <?php
                              if($row_Q2[$RowKeyExist]["TICKETCODE"]=='1'){ //"1" is booked
                                 echo "style='font-size:25; font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free; display: inline-block; content: \f630;  font-weight: 900;  color:grey;'";
                              }elseif($row_Q2[$RowKeyExist]["TICKETCODE"]=='2'){ //"2" is bought
                                 echo "style='font-size:25; font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free; display: inline-block; content: \f630;  font-weight: 900;  color:red;'";
                              }elseif($row_Q2[$RowKeyExist]["TICKETCODE"]=='0'){ //"0" is temp bought in db and not current user
                                 echo "style='font-size:25; font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free; display: inline-block; content: \f630;  font-weight: 900;  color:grey;'";
                              }elseif($row_Q2[$RowKeyExist]["TICKETCODE"]==null){ //"null" is vacant
                                 echo "style='font-size:25; font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free; display: inline-block; content: \f630;  font-weight: 900;  color:green;'";
                              }
                           ?>
                           </label>
                           <div>
                              <label><?=$row_Q2[$RowKeyExist]["SEATLABEL"];?></label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  <?php
                     }else{
                  ?>
                     <div class="d-none">
                        <label class="fas fa-chair SEATIMAGE" style="font-size:25; font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free; display: inline-block; content: \f630;  font-weight: 900;  color:purple;"></label>
                        <div>
                           <label>NONE</label>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  <?php
                     }
                  ?>
                  </div>
               <?php
                  }
               ?>
               </div>
            <?php
               }
            ?>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `overfow:auto;`to the div for which you want too add scroll

Comment: @XenioGracias But i already add overflow-x:auto;... do i still need to add overflow:auto. Anyway it doesnt work. still the same ouput. When comes to 18col, the 19th col breaks into newline

Comment: @KirpalSingh Please post just HTML and CSS code so that others can modify it to help you quickly.

Comment: @Divanshu That all the code i have for html, and inline css. No external css file. Only have additional jquery but not related to css or html modification.

Comment: @KirpalSingh The code you have posted has embedded PHP. Just share HTML and CSS by hardcoding the things that your PHP code would generate during runtime. The community can work easily with HTML and CSS code and can help you quickly.

Comment: the `lable class="SEATIMAGE"` closing tag is wrong

Comment: @Divanshu Since its php based and i need to generate up to 20 columns, it will look ugly if i post it here, so i share in this link    https://codeshare.io/aJK3Mr

Comment: @KirpalSingh Please check. I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you want to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        .my-div {
            width: 300px;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            border: 2px solid white;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
                <div class="my-div">
                    my div   
                </div>
                <div class="my-div">
                    my div
                </div>
                <div class="my-div">
                    my div
                </div>
                <div class="my-div">
                   my div
                </div>
                <div class="my-div">
                    my div
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is screeshot:
[image]

Comment: what is the content of "my-div" class?

Comment: @KirpalSingh You can put custom HTML and CSS in "my-div" div. So, as per your question that div would be generated via your PHP loop.

Comment: i simply tried to compile your code in a separate file to check the outcome but now the rows are vertical not horizontal. Even if i add inline block to row

Comment: @KirpalSingh Please share the screenshot.

Comment: @KirpalSingh I have edited the answer to include the full working code. Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* The heart of the matter */
.testimonial-group > .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.testimonial-group > .row > .col-xs-4 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

/* Decorations */
.col-xs-4 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 18px; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) { background: #c69; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #69c; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container testimonial-group">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4">1</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">2</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">3</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">4</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">5</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">6</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">7</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">8</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
/* The heart of the matter */
.testimonial-group > .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.testimonial-group > .row > .col-xs-4 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

/* Decorations */
.col-xs-4 { color: #fff; font-size: 48px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 18px; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+1) { background: #c69; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+2) { background: #9c6; }
.col-xs-4:nth-child(3n+3) { background: #69c; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container testimonial-group">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4">1</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">2</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">3</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">4</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">5</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">6</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">7</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">8</div><!--
 --><div class="col-xs-4">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```